# How to build authentication and authorization API for mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, rest, security, authentication

I have to build a backend API for the mobile app and I have difficulties with authentication and authorization part. In my previous web projects, everything was ready and I just implemented the business logic. This is the first time I need to build auth part too.

Registration flow looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsdq5.png).

And Login flow like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBZex.png).

I want to use JWT access and refresh tokens, but don't know how to generate all this authentication and authorization flow in the backend, should I add something special for biometric auth? If you send me tools or link where I can figure all this out I'll be really happy.

Comment: in which technology are you building your backend stuff. node??

Comment: @nca kotlin, spring

Comment: Fetch a book or some webinars on Spring Security in combination with Spring Boot.

Comment: @MarekPuchalski thanks! I started to figure out how things work. Now I'm analyzing [kong](https://konghq.com/). looks promising

Comment: I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyVHNJNriUQ) about [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) and it clarified a lot of stuff for me